# Conditional binding based on flag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a Kendo-UI Grid with an AJAX datasource.
I am working with ASP.NET-MVC.

The model looks like this:

```
public class QuestionModelPlayer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
    public int? NummericAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool isTextQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

If the bool `IsTextQuestion` is true I want the users have an incell textbox which binds to the field `TextAnswer`. If the value is false I want to bind it to the `NummericAnswer` property.

How can I do this?
I think i need to use a Template or ClientTemplate?

Comment: StackOverflow questions are not only for the benefit of the person asking the question, but also for the benefit of future readers finding this question on Google. Thus, please do not vandalize your question after you have found a solution; future readers with the same question will thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Telerik documentation:

> If the grid is ajax bound use the ClientTemplate method. The value should be a string which represents a valid Kendo Template.

A couple of snippets sourced from their doco and roughly adapted to your situation (but not tested!) show how it can be done. First as some inline javascript code:

```
columns.Bound(q => q.isTextQuestion)
       .ClientTemplate (
    "# if (isTextQuestion == true) { #" +
        "#: TextAnswer #" +
    "# } else { #" +
        "#: NummericAnswer #" +
    "# } #"
);
```

or alternatively by calling a javascript function:

```
 columns.Bound(q => q.isTextQuestion)
        .ClientTemplate("#= getAnswer(data) #");


<script>
    function getAnswer(question) {

        var html = kendo.format( "<text>{0}</text>"
                                ,question.isTextQuestion 
                                    ? question.TextAnswer 
                                    : question.NummericAnswer 
                                );

        return html;
    }
</script>
```

Check the FAQ item [*Grid Frequently Asked Questions: Displaying Values*](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#grid-frequently-asked-questions) for lots more examples.

Comment: Thanks!, that did the job